# Changing API-version connecting to Azure Confidential Ledger in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-confidential-ledger

I want to connect and query from my "Azure Confidential Ledger" with the following code in Python:

```
from azure.confidentialledger import ConfidentialLedgerClient
from azure.confidentialledger.certificate import ConfidentialLedgerCertificateClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

identity_client = ConfidentialLedgerCertificateClient()
network_identity = identity_client.get_ledger_identity(
    ledger_id="testACL"
)

ledger_tls_cert_file_name = "ledger_certificate.pem"
with open(ledger_tls_cert_file_name, "w") as cert_file:
    cert_file.write(network_identity["ledgerTlsCertificate"])

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ledger_client = ConfidentialLedgerClient(
    endpoint="https://testACL.confidential-ledger.azure.com",
    credential=credential,
    ledger_certificate_path=ledger_tls_cert_file_name
)

ranged_result = ledger_client.list_ledger_entries()

for i, r in enumerate(ranged_result):
    print(i, r)
```

However, I faced the following error that ask me to change "api-version" from 2022-05-13" to "2022-04-20-preview":

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "X", line 23, in for i, r in
> enumerate(ranged_result):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py",
> line 128, in next return next(self._page_iterator)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py",
> line 76, in next self._response =
> self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\confidentialledger_operations_operations.py",
> line 732, in get_next raise HttpResponseError(response=response)
> azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (QueryParameterError) Parsed
> api-version 2022-05-13 is not available. Please use one of the
> following versions: 2022-04-20-preview,0.1-preview Code:
> QueryParameterError Message: Parsed api-version 2022-05-13 is not
> available. Please use one of the following versions:
> 2022-04-20-preview,0.1-preview

How should I change "api-version" in python for connecting to the Azure Confidential Ledger?

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT
would you please advise me what did you edit in my question?

Comment: I have removed `azure-web-app-services` tag since `azure confidential ledger` both are 2 different services.